# Why same browser same screen,different clientWidth of <html> node

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am writing a simple blog using ruby on rails.
  when I open my blog index.html in chrome, the entire page's size is 755*698(width*height), that is, the  node's clientHeight is 755, when I open its source code, copy it into a test.html, it's page's size is 944*1000, and I open index.html in firefox, it size is 946*617,
so I think it maybe some javascript or css changed its size, when I remove all css and javascripts in the index.page, it size is , it width is still 755.2*2000?

[image: index.html after trim css and javascript]

[image: index.html's source code]

obviously, index.html has a bigger font or(zoom i think) than source code

I don't know what is the exact reason.

I found that the index.html's zoom is 125% and the test.html's zoom is 100%, when I adjust zoom to 100%, its clientHeight becomes 944*2123, so it almost equal. But the question is, I didn't set the zoom. Maybe I accidently zoom the page. then the session remember this setting for my site. hah!

Comment: There's no guarantee that the `<html>` element will have size at all, nor that it will be the same height as the window, document or anything else? You probably want to check the documents height, and if that's not the same, then something is different, obviously!

Comment: @adeneo sorry, I have mistype clientWidth. I mean the  width of the entire visible area

Comment: Wouldn't that be the windows with ?